# Need Query to pull Distinct list of numbers from multiple fields in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
tent    slot1    slot2    slot3
1       5        11       2
2       8        16       4
3       1        3        12
```

I need a list of all of the numbers in the slots, so results would look like:

```
user_id
1
2
3
4
5
8
11
12
16
```

I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN tents t ON t.slot1 = u.user_id
   AND t.slot2 = u.user_id
   AND t.slot3 = u.user_id
ORDER BY u.user_id_id ASC
```

But it only seems to give me the numbers from slot1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use `EXISTS` for this:

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tents
    WHERE u.user_id IN (slot1,slot2,slot3)
)
```

If you don't need to `join` to the `users` table, then you can use `UNION` to get a distinct list of values from the slot fields:

```
SELECT slot1 user FROM tents
UNION
SELECT slot2 user FROM tents
UNION
SELECT slot3 user FROM tents
```

Comment: @woot -- I didn't realize the OP wanted to join on the users table, so I updated the answer.

Comment: Yep I saw. :)  I still prefer these over the OPs, I was just showing him how to fix what he has.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you really mean OR and not AND?  And you want an INNER join to only show the matches.

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.user_id
FROM users u
INNER JOIN tents t ON t.slot1 = u.user_id
   OR t.slot2 = u.user_id
   OR t.slot3 = u.user_id
ORDER BY u.user_id ASC
```